# How to dynamically build calls to a function in a module

Tags: module, lua

I have a bunch of generated modules with a naming scheme similar to lib1_0 where 1 is major ver and 0 is minor ver. Inside each is around 300 functions named like type_156.

I pick up input and piece together which function from which module I need to execute based on external factors.

I would like to be able to piece together a function call based on those factors

I have tried various loadstring() (only works on local stuff, not modules) _G[] which looks like the same thing

### lib1_0.lua

```
local lib1_0 = {}

function lib1_0.type_1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    print(arg1, arg2, arg3)
end

function lib1_0.type_2(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    print(arg1, arg2, arg3)
end

return lib1_0
```

### mainfile.lua

```
call1_0 = require(lib1_0)
call1_2 = require(lib1_2)
call2_0 = require(lib2_0)

-- do stuff and find that I want to execute lib1_0 function 2 based on external factors

major = 1
minor = 0
func2run = 2

call = "call" .. major .. "_" .. minor .. ".type_" .. func2run
_G[call]("test1", "test2", "test3")
--does not work, just an example of what I want to do
```

Any solutions? am I missing something obvious? I am very new to Lua so I could well have just missed the obvious

Comment: `_G["call" .. major .. "_" .. minor]["type_" .. func2run]` - it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note the quotes in the require() call.
Also, see [Programming in Lua (PiL) 4th edition, p148-149](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.html) for more about load().

```
call1_0 = require("lib1_0")

-- example of desired outcome
call1_0.type_2("x","y","z")             --> x     y   z

-- build up call from pieces
local major, minor, fnum = 1, 0, 2
local args = "'x', 'y', 'z'"
local codestr = string.format("call%d_%d.type_%d(%s)", major, minor, fnum, args)
print(codestr)                          --> call1_0.type_2('x', 'y', 'z')
local code = load(codestr)
code()                                  --> x     y   z
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is what I was missing. I really need to look deeper into learning Lua better but this is a "generate me a Lua file for this" and I am starting from scratch. Again, thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

```
local call_1 = require(lib1_0)
package.loaded.call_1 = call_1
package.loaded["lib1_0"] = nil

local call_2 = require(lib1_0)
package.loaded.call_2 = call_2
package.loaded["lib1_0"] = nil
```

Comment: Please don't just post code as answer, include an explanation what it does and how (and why) it solves the problem of the question.